# How to show the “Previous/Next/Done” bar with a UITextView

Tags: iphone, keyboard

i've seen a "Previous/Next/Done" bar above the keyboard when entering text in a webview on an iPhone. i want to use this built in bar in an app that i'm making in conjunction with a UITextView. i have seen a very similar looking bar above the keyboard in several apps. my guess is this is either some hand made bar that just looks like the bar i want or the programmer figured out a way to show the actual bar. assuming its the actual bar and not a hand made bar how do you get it to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in Prev/Next/Done bar, you have to create it yourself.

**SEE ALSO:**

- [Programatically align a toolbar on top of the iPhone keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158574/programatically-align-a-toolbar-on-top-of-the-iphone-keyboard)
- [How to find out what UITextField caused a UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604327/how-to-find-out-what-uitextfield-caused-a-uikeyboardwillshownotification)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [XCDFormInputAccessoryView](https://github.com/0xced/XCDFormInputAccessoryView/) which is an input accessory view with previous/next/done buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Create this method and call it on ViewWillLoad:

```
        - (void) keyboardToolbarSetup
{
    if(self.keyboardToolbar==nil)
        {
        self.keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(anyAction)];

        UIBarButtonItem *extraSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(anyOtherAction)];


        NSArray *toolbarButtons = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:cancelButton,extraSpace,doneButton, nil];

        [self.keyboardToolbar setItems:toolbarButtons];

        self.myTextView.inputAccessoryView=self.keyboardToolbar;
        }
}
```